# Change 'add to cart' text when product is sold out

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

He everyone I would like to change the button "in de winkelmand" to sold-out when the product is sold out.

I have tried to disable the product single like attached below to get rid of that weird looking box.

But now need to change the text

```css
.product .single_variation {
    display: none !important;
}

nm-variable-add-to-cart-button single_add_to_cart_button button alt disabled wc-variation-is-unavailable
```

Unfortunately without a result, can anyone point me in the right direction?

> https://www.peachandhoney.nl/product/bella-rose-top/

is the link to the site. Xs is sold out on this product the rest is in stock.

Thank you.

Comment: Avoid 'I want, can someone do it for me?' questions. Include code and show what you have tried so far. Consider reading this guide from about asking good questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. 
Low-effort questions will receive downvotes and will eventually be closed by a moderator.

Comment: Just confirming, You want to get sold-out on each product when the product respective is out of stock. right?

Answer (score 1):

Want to change "sold Out" text with another text, then this will solve your problem with WooCommerce Way. Please add this code to your theme functions.php. But please don't forget to use a child theme

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability_text', 'amc_change_out_of_stock_text', 10, 2 );

 function amc_change_out_of_stock_text( $availability, $product ){

    if ( ! $product->is_in_stock() ) {

        $availability = __( 'in de winkelmand', 'woocommerce' );

    }

    return $availability;

 }
```

Comment: When adding this nothing happens? Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you want to change the text? The `add to cart` text is filterable. Using the filter `woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text`.  This will show the button as long as you allow backorders.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'dd_custom_single_add_to_cart_text' ); 
function dd_custom_single_add_to_cart_text(){
    global $product;
    if ($product->get_stock_status() !== 'instock'){
        return __( 'Sold Out', 'woocommerce' );
    } else {
        return __( 'Add to cart', 'woocommerce' );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine. Tested and confirmed.

```
function change_loop_add_to_cart_button( $button, $product, $args = array() ) {
    if( !$product->is_in_stock() ){
        $button = '<a class="button disabled" style="cursor:not-allowed;color:#777;background-color:#aaa;">'.__('Sold Out', 'woocommerce').'</a>';
    }
   return $button;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'change_loop_add_to_cart_button', 20, 3 );
```

Comment: i get this error when implementing Your PHP code changes were rolled back due to an error on line 1059 of file wp-content/themes/savoy/functions.php. Please fix and try saving again.

Cannot redeclare change_loop_add_to_cart_button() (previously declared in wp-content/themes/savoy/functions.php:972)

Comment: @QuintyvanDijk the function name in my answer `change_loop_add_to_cart_button` is already used in your functions.php. So  change every occurance of the name `change_loop_add_to_cart_button` in the code above to some other name like `change_loop_add_to_cart_button_new`

Comment: Thank you did that and now I can put in the code but nothing happend any idea why?

Comment: @QuintyvanDijk The theme you added the code mightn't be activated. Or the function name in function definition and hook callback might be different. Or the product mightn't be out of stock. Cannot figure out exact issue without inspecting.